# Footer não redimensiona

Tags: html, css, posicionamento, footer

Boa noite. Meu problema é o seguinte, quando tela é muito pequena e é mostrado a barra de rolagem o footer não extende mais para 100%.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>JSON2CSV</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="app">
            <di>
                <h1 id="app-title">JSON to CSV</h1>
            </di>
            <div class="div-input">
                <label for="text-input">JSON</label><br>
                <textarea name="" id="text-input" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="div-actions">
                <div class="div-buttons">
                    <input type="button" value="Convert" class="button" id="button-convert" onclick="onConvert();">
                    <input type="button" value="Clear" class="button" id="button-clean" onclick="onClean();">
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="div-output">
                <label for="text-output">CSV</label><br>
                <textarea name="" id="text-output" cols="30" rows="10" readonly></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <p class="footer-content">Made with <span id="heart-emoji">❤</span> by <a href="http://" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" id="link-profile">Thiago</a></p>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: #03A9F4;
    width: 100%;
}

input[type],
textarea {
    border: 1px solid #03A9F4;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    overflow: auto;
    resize: none;
}

.div-input,
.div-output {
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
    height: 90%;
}

.div-actions {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    height: 90%;
}

.div-buttons {
    top: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#app {
    width: 700px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#app-title {
    text-align: center;
    color: #03A9F4;
}

label {
    color: #03A9F4;
}

.button {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px;
}

.button:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

#button-clean,
#button-convert {
    border: 1px solid #03A9F4;
    width: 100px;
}

#button-convert {
    background-color: #03A9F4;
    color: white;
}

#button-clean {
    background-color: white;
    color: #03A9F4;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

footer {
    background-color: black;
    height: 100px;
    min-width: 100vw;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
}

.footer-content {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: grey;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#heart-emoji {
    color: red;
}

#link-profile:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#link-profile:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: white;
}
```

**Exemplo:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que seu `footer` está com o `min-width: 100vw`, enquanto seu `#app` está com `width: 700px`.

Então, quando a largura da tela é menor do que `700px`, o `#app` não diminui (criando uma rolagem horizontal) e o `footer` acompanha a largura da tela.

Para corrigir, adicione esses estilos ao seu `footer`:

```css
/* Não ficará menor do que o #app */
min-width: 700px;

/* Quando a tela for maior do que 700px de largura, o footer ocupará a largura inteira */
width: 100vw;
```

Answer (score -2):

Salve!
Sou novo na comunidade, mas pelo o que eu entendi é como o amigo mencionou aqui.
Você terá que efetuar a troca do min-width.
Fiz o teste aqui e funcionou colocando o widht em 721px.
Quase a mesma largura do #app.
tenta aí e dá uma olhada de como irá ficar.

footer {
background-color: black;
height: 100px;
width: 721px;
}